# how to write regex for list of items sharing the same roots

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

So I have a list of keywords:
`['xxxxl','xxxl','xxl','xl','xxxxt','xxxt','xxt','xt']`
In bigquery, I want to write a regex, inside the following sql code

```
SELECT my_column
FROM table
REGEXP_CONTAINS(lower(my_column),regex)
```

so that my output table contains only the values that don't match any of the items in keywords list.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.lookup_table` AS (
  SELECT ['xxxxl','xxxl','xxl','xl','xxxxt','xxxt','xxt','xt'] keywords
)
SELECT my_column
FROM `project.dataset.table`, 
  (SELECT STRING_AGG(LOWER(keyword), '|') exclude_pattern 
  FROM `project.dataset.lookup_table`, 
  UNNEST(keywords) keyword)
WHERE NOT REGEXP_CONTAINS(LOWER(my_column), exclude_pattern)
```

You can test / play with above using below simplified example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.lookup_table` AS (
  SELECT ['xxxxl','xxxl','xxl','xl','xxxxt','xxxt','xxt','xt'] keywords
), `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'xxxxl' my_column UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abc'
)
SELECT my_column
FROM `project.dataset.table`, 
  (SELECT STRING_AGG(LOWER(keyword), '|') exclude_pattern 
  FROM `project.dataset.lookup_table`, 
  UNNEST(keywords) keyword)
WHERE NOT REGEXP_CONTAINS(LOWER(my_column), exclude_pattern)
```

with output

```
Row my_column    
1   abc
```